# Change the sliders as per the time of the day

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to show different sliders as per the time of the day. For example from 0-9am 'slider set 1', from 9am-12pm 'slider set 2', and so on. As I am new to java script please help me to solve. I have some code with me which will display different images on different time. Sharing here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p id="slider"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var greeting;
var time = new Date().getHours();
if (time>=0 && time<10) {
    greeting = '<img     src="http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/demos/demo/img/01.jpg"/>'
} else if (time>=10 && time< 12) {
    greeting = '<img src="http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/demos/demo/img/02.jpg"/>'
} else if (time>=12 && time< 16) {
    greeting = '<img src="http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/demos/demo/img/03.jpg"/>';
} else if (time>=16 && time< 20) {
    greeting = '<img src="http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/demos/demo/img/04.jpg"/>'
} else {
    greeting = '<img src="http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/demos/demo/img/05.jpg"/>'
}
document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = greeting;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set an interval using `window.setInterval(function(){myFunction(); }, time)` where time can be 1 minute or 1 second. You can refer this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/g7jeq6qy/

Comment: Thanks, but you are not getting my point. Now in my code just a single image is displaying. I want sliders(Banners) there.

Comment: For that you may need to create slider using jquery plugins like owl, bxslider etc.

Comment: I have those sliders with me. But I don't know to integrate with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used owl carousel here. Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/g7jeq6qy/6/).

I have set an interval of 2000ms for now to check(as dealing with hours won't be practical for testing) and hence commented your code. Instead of changing HTML I have changed slides here.

```
if (time >= 0 && time < 10) {
  owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
} else if (time >= 10 && time < 12) {
  owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
} else if (time >= 12 && time < 16) {
  owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
} else if (time >= 16 && time < 20) {
  owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
} else {    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the banners are not sliding..?

Comment: In your code banners are changing from the same slider in time gap. But I want different set of sliders to be called at different time. What I mean to say is, from morning 6 to 10am i want to display 1 set of slider and from 10 to 12 different set and from 12 to 3pm another set and so on.. Please help me...